# SLF4j API to read Logs

Tags: java, slf4j

I am using SLF4j in my java application to store the logs and it works fine. Now i need to retrieve the logs generated by my application . Is there any API SLF4J provide to retrieve the logs?

I tried looking into the manual of SL4j but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

SLF4j does not provide an API to read logs.
It is strictly a tool for writing logs.
Logs are just text files,
read them like any other text file.

Check out the answer to this question: [reading log file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934818/reading-log-file-in-java)